# Deleting duplicate text lines using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, filter, duplicates, findstr

I am creating a text file that displays a file extenstion of each file in the folder. I want to get rid of duplicate since it creates a line of text for each file.

After a bit of searching, I figured out I should use findstr to overwrite the initial file with a new version that has specific extension removed (after I write it to the filtered file).

```
for %%A in (*.*) do echo %%~xA >> initial.txt
for /F %%B in (initial.txt) do (
    echo %%B >> filtered.txt
    for /F %%C in (initial.txt) do findstr /v %%C initial.txt > initial.txt
)
```

but it leaves the initial file empty (as expected) while still copying every single line to the filtered.txt file.
I'd be very glad for some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create the file `filtered.txt` immediately, there is no need for `initial.txt`:

```
> "filtered.txt" rem/
for %%A in ("*.*") do (
    > nul find /I "%%~xA" "filtered.txt"
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        >> "filtered.txt" echo %%~xA
    )
)
```

Here I am using `find` rather than `findstr` because only simple literal strings are to be searched. `find` (like `findstr`) sets the `ErrorLevel` to `0` if at least one match is encountered, and to `1` if none has been found.

Depending on the returned `ErrorLevel`, the currently iterated file extension in `%%~xA` is echoed and redirected into `filtered.txt` or not. So if `filtered.txt` already contains the current item, it is not echoed, but if no match is encountered, the item is appended to the file.

The first line creates an empty file `filtered.txt` for `find` not to fail for its first execution.

---

If you want to use the file `initial.txt` anyway, you could do the following:

```
>> "initial.txt" (
    for %%A in ("*.*") do echo %%~xA
)
> "filtered.txt" rem/
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%A in ("initial.txt") do (
    > nul find /I "%%~xA" "filtered.txt"
    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        >> "filtered.txt" echo %%~xA
    )
)
```

This code is almost the same as above; the only differences are the preceded creation of `initial.txt` (potentionally containing duplicates), and the enumeration of its content (by `for /F`) rather than enumerating the current directory directly.

Comment: Thank you! The first example looks like exactly what I need and done in more efficient way. I didn't realize I could use errorlevels after find command. However you missed an "x" in the last reference to variable "A" which made it copy whole file names instead of extensions. I fixed it for myself, so no big deal here. Appreciate your help!